# Part specification using list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, argument-patterns

How to use a `list` to specify part of another nested list `mat`? We don't want to write `mat[[list[[1]],list[[2]],list[[3]],...]]`.

```
mat = RandomInteger[10, {5, 6, 7, 8}];
list = {3, 4, 6};
mat[[3, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of options.

Use Extract instead:

```
Extract[mat, list]
```

Apply Sequence to the list:

```
mat[[Sequence @@ list]]
```

Comment: Also, `mat[[##]] & @@ list`

Answer (score 3):

A variation could be:

```
Fold[Part, mat, list]
```

> `{9, 0, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4, 3}`

Answer (score 2):

```
m = Partition[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 3];

i = {1, 3, 4, 6};
```

Using `Query`

```
Query[i] @ m
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k", "l"}, {"p", "q", "r"}}

Using `Map` and `Part`

```
m[[#]] & /@ i
```

> {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k", "l"}, {"p", "q", "r"}}

Comment: (+1) Nice. Interestingly, in this case `Query` appears  to be using ``GeneralUtilities`Slice[i][m]`` 'under the hood', and `Query[i, 2][m]` produces `{"b", "h", "k", "q"}` as does ``GeneralUtilities`Slice[i,2][m]``

Comment: Thank you for this interesting observation. Will explore `Slice` further.